Saving changes made to ASP.Net gridview webform cell is not working
Have a nice day ahead. I am having a problem in saving the contents of gridview cells to database. Here's the scenario. My gridview contains timesheet of employee. The employee can move the timesheet cell data from one cell to another but cannot tamper its data. I use javascript to right-click to a cell and left-click to move the content of a cell to a desired cell. It is working fine. The problem is when I save the contents of gridview after the modifications made to cells. The original contents of cell is saved to database, not the modified contents of the gridview. I am asking for your brilliant minds to help me solve my problem.
Here's my javascript code for moving cell content to another cell:
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var sourceCellIndex = -1; // Variable to store the index of the source cell

            // Function to handle right-click on a cell
            $(document).on("contextmenu", "#<%= gvTimesheet.ClientID %> td", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default context menu
            sourceCellIndex = $(this).index(); // Get the index of the clicked cell
            alert("Selected Data: " + $(this).text()); // Display an alert with the text of the clicked cell
            return false;
        });

        // Function to handle left-click on a cell
        $(document).on("click", "#<%= gvTimesheet.ClientID %> td", function () {
            if (sourceCellIndex !== -1) { // Check if a source cell has been selected
                var destinationCellIndex = $(this).index(); // Get the index of the clicked cell

                // Transfer the text from the source cell to the destination cell
                var sourceText = $("tr").eq($(this).closest("tr").index()).find("td").eq(sourceCellIndex).text();
                $(this).text(sourceText); // Set the text of the destination cell
                $("tr").eq($(this).closest("tr").index()).find("td").eq(sourceCellIndex).text(""); // Clear the text of the source cell

                // Update hidden fields based on source and destination cell indices
                var sourceHiddenField, destinationHiddenField;
                if (sourceCellIndex === 2) {
                    sourceHiddenField = $("#<%= hiddenInAM.ClientID %>");
                } else if (sourceCellIndex === 3) {
                    sourceHiddenField = $("#<%= hiddenOutAM.ClientID %>");
                }
                if (destinationCellIndex === 4) {
                    destinationHiddenField = $("#<%= hiddenInPM.ClientID %>");
                } else if (destinationCellIndex === 5) {
                    destinationHiddenField = $("#<%= hiddenOutPM.ClientID %>");
                }

                if (sourceHiddenField && destinationHiddenField) {
                    destinationHiddenField.val(sourceText); // Update the value of the destination hidden field
                    sourceHiddenField.val(""); // Clear the value of the source hidden field
                }

                // Call captureChanges to capture the modified data
                var modifiedData = captureChanges();

                // Call saveChangesToServer to save the modified data
                saveChangesToServer(modifiedData);
                /*alert("Data transferred successfully!");*/

                sourceCellIndex = -1; // Reset the source cell index
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

Code behind:
public void saveTimesheet()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Conn.strCon);
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvTimesheet.Rows)
                    {
                    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                    {
string lblDate = row.Cells[0].Text;
                            string lblDay = row.Cells[1].Text;

                            amIn = row.Cells[2].Text;
                            amOut = row.Cells[3].Text;
                            pmIn = row.Cells[4].Text;
                            pmOut = row.Cells[5].Text;
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_timesheet(compcde,empno,empnem,paytype,cstctr,bioDate,bioDay,inAM,outAM,inPM,outPM,reghrs,OT,remarks,firstApprover,secondApprover,status) VALUES (@compcde,@empno,@empnem,@paytype,@cstctr,@bioDate,@bioDay,@inAM,@outAM,@inPM,@outPM,@reghrs,@OT,@remarks,@firstApprover,@secondApprover,@status) ", conn);
                                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compcde", comp_cde);
                                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empno", IDNo);
                                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empnem", name);
                                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paytype", paytype);
                                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cstctr", costctr);
                                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bioDate", lblDate);
                                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bioDay", lblDay);
                                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inAM", amIN);
                                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@outAM", amOUt);
                                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inPM", pmIN);
                                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@outPM", pmOUt);
if (double.TryParse(lblOTHrs, out OTHrs))
                                {
                                    if (OTHrs > 0)
                                    {
                                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reghrs", 8.0);
                                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OT", OTHrs);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reghrs", lblRegHrs);
                                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OT", 0.0);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reghrs", lblRegHrs);
                                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OT", 0.0);
                                }
                                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remarks", lblRemarks);
                                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstApprover", txtApprover.Text);
                                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@secondApprover", txtApprover2.Text);
                                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "For Approval");
                               
                                conn.Open();
                                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                conn.Close();
}
}
}
}

I tried to add another javascript to catch the changes made to cells but this code is not working.
javascript code:
<script>
        // Example usage when the user clicks a "Save" button
        $('#btnSave').click(function () {
            // Capture changes made by the user
            var modifiedData = captureChanges();

            // Send modified data to the server for saving
            saveChangesToServer(modifiedData);
        });

        // Function to capture changes made by the user
        function captureChanges() {
            var modifiedData = []; // Array to store modified timesheet data

            // Loop through each row in the GridView
            $('#<%= gvTimesheet.ClientID %> tr').each(function (index, row) {
                var rowData = []; // Array to store data for the current row

                // Loop through each cell in the row
                $(row).find('td').each(function (cellIndex, cell) {
                    // Check if the cell has been modified (you may need to implement your own logic here)
                    // For example, check if the cell's text has changed from its original value

                    // Retrieve the updated value from the cell
                    var updatedValue = $(cell).text();

                    // Add the updated value to the rowData array
                    rowData.push(updatedValue);
                });

                // Add the rowData array to the modifiedData array
                modifiedData.push(rowData);
            });

            // Return the modifiedData array containing all the changes made by the user
            return modifiedData;
        }

        // Function to send modified data to the server for saving
        function saveChangesToServer(modifiedData) {
            // Convert modified data to JSON
            var jsonData = JSON.stringify(modifiedData);

            // Make an AJAX call to the server-side method to save the data
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Create_Timesheet.aspx/SaveTimesheetData',
                data: { jsonData: jsonData },
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    // Handle success response from the server
                    alert(response.d); // Display success message
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    // Handle error response from the server
                    console.error(error); // Log the error to the console
                    alert('Error occurred while saving data. Please try again.'); // Display error message
                }
            });
        }



    </script>

Code behind:
[WebMethod]
        public static string SaveTimesheetData(string jsonData)
        {
            try
            {
                
                // Deserialize the JSON data received from the client
                // For simplicity, let's assume jsonData is an array of arrays representing the modified timesheet data
                // You'll need to adjust this based on your actual JSON structure
                string[][] modifiedTimesheetData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[][]>(jsonData);

                // Process the modified timesheet data and update the database accordingly
                foreach (var rowData in modifiedTimesheetData)
                {
                    amIn= rowData[0]; // Assuming the first element represents timeIn-AM
                    amOut= rowData[1]; // Assuming the second element represents timeOut-AM
                    pmIn= rowData[2]; // Assuming the third element represents timeIn-PM
                    pmOut= rowData[3];
                    
                }

                // Return a success message to the client
                return "Timesheet data saved successfully!";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log the exception or handle it as needed
                return "Error saving timesheet data: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }

